# loss is stuck and cannot get what I want in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

a = tf.range(1, 100, dtype = float)
r = tf.random.uniform(shape = a.shape) / 10
b = tf.square(a) + r

def create_model(x, y):
    opt = "adam"
    ls = "mean_squared_error"
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, input_shape = [1], activation = "relu"),
                                 tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 3),
                                 tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2),
                                 tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1)])
    model.compile(optimizer = opt,
                  loss = ls)
    model.fit(x, y, epochs = 1000, verbose = 2)

    

model = create_model(a, b)
```

I am a beginner in TensorFlow. I want to predict quadratic function, so I write a model like above. But the loss always stuck and cannot get right output. After 1000 epoch, I get this result.

```
Epoch 1000/1000
4/4 - 0s - loss: 1161095.8750
```

I tried changing epoch or adding more layers, but it didn't work. I am searching for a long time on net, but no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to improve the performance of your model:

1. You might want to consider normalizing your input data a and b. This
   can help the optimization process converge faster and potentially
   lead to better results. You can do this by subtracting the mean of a
   and b from each element and then dividing by their standard
   deviation.
2. You might want to try using a different optimizer. The Adam
   optimizer is a good choice in many cases, but there are other
   optimizers that might work better for your particular problem. You
   can try using a different optimizer by passing a different string to
   the optimizer argument of the compile method.
3. You might want to try using a different loss function. The mean
   squared error loss is often used for regression problems, but there
   are other loss functions that might work better for your particular
   problem. You can try using a different loss function by passing a
   different string to the loss argument of the compile method.
4. You might want to try using a different number of layers or a
   different number of units per layer. Increasing the complexity of
   your model might help it capture the quadratic relationship in your
   data better, but it could also lead to overfitting if you are not
   careful.

I hope these suggestions help! If you are still having trouble, please let me know and I would be happy to help further.